# Django Rest Framework override viewset list method optionally?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to modify the list method of a ViewSet.

I need to return data only if a condition satisfies. otherwise the default behaviour should be invoked.

```
def list(self, request):
    """Allow profile listing only for admin and super admins."""

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == constants.Constants.ADMIN:
        #invoke default behaviour
        pass 
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

But this code does not work in case the condition passes.

I'm new to Django and DRF, is there a better way to do this? Or how can I fix the above code?

Comment: Seems like you're also new to python: read [what `pass` does in a python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) reference and [how to subclass in python](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the default behaviour you need to invoke `return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)` instead of `pass`.

Also I am not sure if 403 wouldn't be better than 405 status code?
So it could look like this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Allow profile listing only for admin and super admins."""

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == constants.Constants.ADMIN:
        #invoke default behaviour
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```